# Definite Integral of sinc function

Tags: integration

> $$\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \operatorname{sinc}(x) \ \mathrm dx$$

How definite integral can be done for a sinc function? I know the integral for sinc function when its limits are from zero to infinity, but what will it be if the limits are $t_1$ and $t_2$ as shown in the attached figure?

Comment: Note the definition of the [Sine Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html):
$$\operatorname*{Si}(z)=\int_0^z \frac{\sin(t)}{t}~dt$$

Comment: Thanks Mr. Projectilemotion  , but the problem is from finding Si(z) ? how can i find it ...? thanks for your hepl

Comment: @projectilemotion , thanks for your help. I found description and solution for the Si(z) in following link:   [link] https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral               But could please tell me, if the following expression is right or not:     Definite Integral for Sinc(Limits [a,b])  = Si(b) - Si(a)

Comment: Indeed, we have:
$$\int_{a}^{b}\operatorname{sinc}(x)~dx=\int_0^b \operatorname{sinc}(x)~dx-\int_0^a\operatorname{sinc}(x)~dx =\operatorname{Si}(b)-\operatorname{Si}(a)$$
I provided the definition on my first comment, since the *unnormalized* $\operatorname{sinc}$ function is defined for $t\neq 0$ as $\operatorname{sinc}(t)=\dfrac{\sin(t)}{t}$.

Comment: The *normalized* $\operatorname*{sinc}$ function can be integrated similarly, except you will have to first use a change of variable on the integral in order to apply the definition of the Sine Integral. On that note, could you please state which definition of $\operatorname*{sinc}$ you are using?

Comment: I use normalized sinc function, i.e. at t=0, the sinc = 1